# Show that if $p > 1$ and $\sup_{n \geq 1} |X_n| \in L^p$ then $\{X_n, n \geq 1\}$ is uniformly integrable.

Tags: probability-theory, lp-spaces, uniform-integrability

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{\Sigma,\mathbb{P}})$ be a complete probability space.

I have to show that $$\lim_{\alpha \to \infty} \sup_{n \geq 1}\int_{\{|X_n| \geq \alpha\}}|X_n|\, d\mathbb{P} = 0$$

assuming title's assumptions and let $\alpha > 0$

my attempt :

$| X_n| \leq \sup_{n\geq 1}|X_n| \leq [\sup_{n\geq 1}|X_n|]^p$

therefore

$$\int_{\{|X_n| \geq \alpha\}}|X_n|\, d\mathbb{P} \leq \int_{\{|X_n| \geq \alpha\}} [\sup_{n\geq 1}|X_n|]^p\, d\mathbb{P} \leq \mathbb{E}[ [\sup_{n\geq 1}|X_n|]^p] < \infty $$

so for every $n \geq 1$

$$\int_{\{|X_n| \geq \alpha\}}|X_n|\, d\mathbb{P} < \infty $$

however I'm not sure this completes the proof because although it's finite it could possibly depend on $n$ and taking the supremum with $n$'s in an expression can cause a blow up.

any hints or help will be greatly appreciated, thanks !

Comment: I think there is a typo in your title since this is untrue in the case $p=1$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267587/family-of-functions-that-are-bounded-in-l1-but-not-uniformly-integrable)). I've edited your title to remove this case. Your attempt doesn't work. The first line is wrong since if $x < 1$, $p>1$ then $x$ is not smaller than $x^p$.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the fact that
$$
\int_{|X_n|\ge \alpha}|X_n|d\Bbb P\le\frac{1}{\alpha^{p-1}}\int_{|X_n|\ge \alpha}|X_n|^pd\Bbb P.
$$ If $\sup\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}\|X_n\|_p=M<\infty$ (our case is a special case of this), then we have
$$
\int_{|X_n|\ge \alpha}|X_n|d\Bbb P\le\frac{1}{\alpha^{p-1}}M^p,\quad\forall n\in\Bbb N.
$$ This gives
$$
\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}\int_{|X_n|\ge \alpha}|X_n|d\Bbb P\le\frac{1}{\alpha^{p-1}}M^p
$$ and we get the desired conclusion by taking $\alpha\to\infty.$

Comment: thanks ! , I actually know this technique to prove that the boundedness in $L^p$ implies uniform integrability, what I fail to see is that $\|\sup_{n \geq 1} X_n\|_p < \infty \implies \sup_{n \geq 1}\|X_n\|_p < \infty$, I'm gonna think about this

Comment: @rapidracim Note that $\int |X_n|^p \leq \int (\sup |X_n|)^p$. This gives the inequality you want since the right hand side is uniform in $n$.

Comment: @RhysSteele I see it now, thanks !