# ’s are uniformly integrable if  ||^ < ∞

Tags: measure-theory, uniform-integrability

I am working on this problem.

If $sup_t E|X_t|^r <\infty$ for some $r>1$, then the $X_t$’s are uniformly integrable. Note that $\mu$ is not finite.

My attempt: Using Holder's inequality, $ \frac{1}{r} + \frac{1}{s} = 1 $

$$E|X_t 1(|X|>\lambda)| ≤ (E|X_t|^r)^\frac{1}{r}  (E|1(|X|>\lambda)|^s)^\frac{1}{s}; $$

$$= \ (E|X_t|^r)^\frac{1}{r} (P(X^s_t>\lambda^s))^\frac{1}{s} $$

$$ ≤\ (E|X_t|^r)^\frac{1}{r} (E|X_t|^s)^\frac{1}{s} \lambda^{-1}$$

$$= (E|X_t|^{r+s})\lambda^{-1}$$

Then

$$ E|X_t 1(|X|>\lambda)| ≤ (E|X_t|^{r+s})\lambda^{-1} $$

Then take the limit of $\lambda \rightarrow \infty $ which will give the result. However, I am not sure if I am on the right track. I would appreciate any tips.

Comment: What is $\mu$ ?

Comment: It's the measure. I meant measurable space is not necessarily finite.

Comment: This question was actually asked before, I was able to find the answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3078530/show-that-if-p-1-and-sup-n-geq-1-x-n-in-lp-then-x-n-n-geq-1?rq=1